# Throw exception if Optional<> value is present

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Suppose I have a Spring Data Repository method.

```
Optional<Branch> findByName(@Nonnull final String name);
```

My business logic is such if I find any value for this method execution  I would throw an exception.

I could do this  for example :

```
Optional.of(branchRepository.findByName(branch.getName()))
                .filter(bo -> !bo.isPresent())
                .orElseThrow(NameNotAvailableException::new);
```

or another way:

```
Optional.of(branchRepository.findByName(branch.getName()))
                .filter(Optional::isEmpty)
                .orElseThrow(NameNotAvailableException::new);
```

I am not sure if using filter, in this case, is appropriate as my method returns `Optional<Branch>` 
not a list. 
It seems that if in JDK if there were ifPresentThrow() method was available that would serve my purpose.

**Yes, this code can be written in an imperative style which I don't want. So my question is the same kind of things ifPresentThrow() can be achieved or there is a better way to do it in a functional style. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: How is tag [tag:spring-data-jpa] relevant to your question? Your question relates purely to class `Optional`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: tags updated thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You'd better use "exists".

```
if (repository.existsByName(branchName)) {
    throw ...
}
```

It more usefull, because it doesn't retrive the object from db, just true/false.

Comment: that's a smart solution but my question was about writing that in funcational way . Thanks anyaway.

Comment: Moshiour asked to do it in functional way but I like your idea. :)

Comment: But, @Moshiour, for this particular case the functional way is inferior, it leads to unnecessarily complicated code. I recommend that instead you use it in other situation where it helps writing clear code.

Comment: @Moshiour You are already using side effects and exceptions. Even if you use Optional, your imperative code will not become functional.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `ifPresent` with block to throw an exception

```
branchRepository.findByName(branch.getName()).ifPresent(s -> {
    throw new NameNotAvailableException();
});
```

Or a simple `if` block also looks cleaner

```
if(branchRepository.findByName(branch.getName()).isPresent()) {
    throw new NameNotAvailableException();
}
```

---

Or you can create a method to just throw an exception

```
public void throwException(Object str) {
    throw new NameNotAvailableException();
}
```

And then just call it

```
branchRepository.findByName(branch.getName()).ifPresent(this::throwException);
```

Comment: yes, that's a way, but curly in brace inside a lambda? that's creating its own lexical scope. In our code review, we discourage using lambda where a curly brace needs to be used.

Comment: But still you are encouraging to create nested `Optional` object to just throw an exception @Moshiour

Comment: yup, and to break that chain I asked that question and in regard to your second modification I mentioned in my question  I don't want to do it in imperative style.

Comment: If your exception is unchecked why not my third approach ? @Moshiour or you don't want to create a method to just throw an exception and even this `orElseThrow(NameNotAvailableException::new)` has it's own lexical scope right ?

Comment: but that's handled by JDK and for that, not my concern. isn't it?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference, but still i'm not the author of jdk @Moshiour

Comment: and @Deadpool, if we create another method to throw an exception then there is a pattern matching some code will throw CodeNotAvaialeException.. etc. and so on..you get the idea. that's extra responsibility.

Comment: @Moshior - I think you arguing with the wrong people.  Deadpool has given you 3 alternatives, and I don't think there are any others that are significantly different.  If none of them is acceptable to you, there's nothing that >>we<< can do about it.  Submit a bug report / request for enhancement to the Java dev team.

Comment: I'm not sure what pattern matchings you have, can you show us an example ? @Moshiour Just another information, you can also use that method to throw different exceptions by using `instanceOf` or based on value

Comment: @Moshiour Honestly(opinion), if you were to think of designing a clean API, then `findByName` for an existence check is also not a clean design(see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58898186/1746118))! And yes `if(branchRepository.findByName(branch.getName()).isPresent())` is the simplest check you can perform with the existing liabilities.